# Column name from txt/csv imported as character in R

Tags: r, character

I use `.txt` files that are generated with complex column names such as
`Basket/Fruit/Many Apples/Pears+ Cherries-/Seeds+ Peel-| Freq. (%)`

However `read.delim()` replaces all spaces and `+` or `-` signs with dots `.`. I require the symbols to make sense of my data down the line.

If I transform my files into `.xlsx` and read through `readxl::read_excel()`, I get the column names in full as `character`.

Can I achieve this somehow directly through my original `.txt` files and `read.delim()`, and not have my symbols in col names replaced?

Comment: Use the argument option `check.names = FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your text file

```
% cat file.txt
Basket/Fruit/Many Apples/Pears+ Cherries-/Seeds+ Peel-| Freq. (%)
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

reading in with e.g. `read.delim`

```
read.delim('file.txt', header=T, check.names=F, sep=" ")
```

Output

```
  Basket/Fruit/Many Apples/Pears+ Cherries-/Seeds+ Peel-| Freq. (%)
1                 1             2                3      4     5   6
2                 2             3                4      5     6   7
```